# Accessing objects via user-defined IDs in JointJS

Tags: jointjs

In JointJS, is it possible to either:

- Set the ID of a cell/element after it's been created?
- Set the ID of a cell/element during the `.clone()` function?
- Access the name of an element* without going via `.attributes.attrs.headerLabel.textWrap.text` ?

* (this is for a `joint.shapes.mapping.Record` element, if it makes a difference)

Answer (score 1):

At least for UML shapes (the class shapes, to be precise) you can change the ID by using `graph.getCell(currentId).prop("id", newId)` or just `cellModel.prop("id", newId)` if you have the model at hand. Be carefull as this sets the new ID on the one cell only - you'll have to cearch for references to thie ID and change them one by one.

As for accessing the name, (again, tested on UML class shapes only) did you try using `cellModel.attr("headerLabel/textWrap/text")` ?